# Merge vs Set statement in SAS

Tags: merge, dataset, sas

I am wondering if there is any difference between **merge** and **set** statements in SAS when using only 1 dataset as source.

**For example:**

```
 data newdata;
 set olddata;
 run;
```

**vs**

```
data newdata;
merge olddata;
by identifier;
run;
```

I cant find any differences in the resulting datasets from each method.

Is there any difference between the two statements in a situation like this?
Thanks.

Comment: Only thing I can think of off the top of my head is the requirement to sort by identifier before the merge statement, which would make the data step useless since you can output sort to a new dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
data a;
set b;
run;
```

and

```
data a;
merge b;
run;
```

other than the likely warning/error you will receive from the merge statement not having a `by` statement.  If you include the `by` statement in both, there becomes no difference at all.

Merge is in fact a special case of Set, as KP6's answer explains.  With only a single dataset, it is identical.